# Incrementing a variable within a loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a dice game in which I want to allow the user to keep some of their rolls, and then reroll others. I store their first 5 rolls in an array called `dieArray` and then print the contents of this array, each die being numbered, and then ask the user which die he/she wants to keep, looping one at a time.

The idea was to then add the value of the die that the user chose to keep to a new array that I called `keepArray`.

My current code for this loop is as follows

```
while(bool != false){
        System.out.print("Would you like to keep a die? y/n: ");
        char ch = scanner.next().charAt(0);


        if(ch == 'n') {
            System.out.println("Exiting----------------------------------------------");
            bool = false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Which die number would you like to keep?: ");
            int keep = scanner.nextInt();
            int i = 0;
            keepArray[i] = die.dieArray[keep];
            i++;
            System.out.println("i value is " + i);
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is that my `i` within the `else` statement is not being incremented. I feel that I am not understanding the fundamentals of `while` loops in Java, because as I see it each time the else loop is accessed, which should be every time the user answers "y" when asked if he/she wants to keep a die, my `i` should be incremented by 1. Clearly it is not.

Comment: As a side note, any comparison using `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, or `!=` will return a `boolean`. For example writing `1 != 2` is the same as writing `true`. With this in mind, if your variable `bool` is `false`, then `bool != false` will return `false`; if `bool` is `true`, then `bool != false` will return `true`. So you can just write `while(bool)` instead of `while(bool != false)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `i` variable is being recreated on every round. You need to declare `int i = 0;` above the loop.